# ARM Template for APIM and App Service dependency

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Relatively new to ARM but I have an issue, I'm creating a template for an API Management but after I create the instance, I want to add that APIM IP to be added to the list of allowed points in the App Service's Network Restrictions.
How would I structure this in a way that it would add the APIM to the App Service List of Allowed Network. My APIM also references the App Service. I'm using Azure DevOps to deploy.

```
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
            ...
            "properties": {
                "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
                    {
                        "ipAddress": "51.XX.XX.XX/32",
                        "action": "Allow",
                        "tag": "Default",
                        "priority": 100,
                        "name": "APIM-Instance",
                        "description": "APIM-Instance"
                    },
                    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the right way -

```
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        ...
        "properties": {
          "siteConfig" {
            "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
                {
                    "ipAddress": "51.XX.XX.XX/32",
                    "action": "Allow",
                    "tag": "Default",
                    "priority": 100,
                    "name": "APIM-Instance",
                    "description": "APIM-Instance"
                },
                ...
             }
             ....
```